# What is the simplest way to offer "change password" in a Community?

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, community-builder, change-password, reset-password

In the Community Administration Login & Registration, there is a "Reset Password" page option that offers:

- Default Page
- Visualforce Page

I would like to expose the "Default Page" in my community so a user can elect to change their password.

In the Community Builder, the "User Profile Menu" does not appear to have a way to offer a "change password" option. Is there some way to access the "Default Page" from say a custom "My Profile" page? Seems a little surprising that this isn't easily added.

The [Site Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) `changePassword` method looks designed for Visualforce; can it be called from an `@AuraEnabled` method?

**PS**

Based on nbrown's answer, I can see "User Settings" in a Customer Service templated community but not in my template. ("Change Password" appears to be a modal built into the "User Settings" component.) Is there **a way to introduce those components after the template creation**?

[image: Customer Service]

[image: Custom]

Comment: That's disappointing that you can't see the component. What template are you using? That could be the factor. I could see the reasoning being a "customer service" template is intended for public consumption, so you need to provide a change password option for lack of any other way to change a password, whereas other communities are accessed by users who have access to another service already and would be able to change their password there.

Comment: Keith, what did you end up doing for this? I'm in an identical situation and don't see great options. I do see Customizable User Settings OOTB component... but it doesn't seem to work... it never displays when put on a page.

Comment: Hi @DonCheadle, This feature hasn't made it out of the backlog so I'm afraid I haven't worked on it.

Comment: @KeithC understood, that's too bad. Could you check out my question here when you have time? It's related, and since you've "been there before" I'd be curious even of a comment from you https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/341819/how-to-use-ootb-component-customizable-user-settings-inside-community

Comment: Hi @DonCheadle, I gave it an upvote but don;'t have anything to contribute.

Answer (score 4):

The template page "User Settings" (accessible via `settings/:userId`) should be automatically included with a community. This page has an OOTB component called Customizable User Settings with a *Change Password* link on it that allows the user to change their password.

Keep in mind this is what I'm seeing in my Customer Service templated community, so customizations may make yours very different.

Comment: Thanks I'll create a community from that template and take a look.

Comment: Not sure why I don't have those; see the **PS** in the question.

Comment: Some downsides to this... Problem #1:
The OOTB User Settings page requires the userId to be passed a parameter in the URL. But you cannot make URL's dynamic... so you would need a custom button in between which does UserInfo.getUserId() and then pass that in the URL.

Problem #2:
The OOTB component Customizable User Settings expects a userId parameter... but I don't see a way to provide it. So even if you just pull that onto your page, to avoid the User Settings URL not being dynamic, you still cannot provide the userId from what I can tell... so these aren't really that helpful?

Answer (score 1):

In Settings\Advanced - check "Show All Components" as highlighted below, you will be able to see all the standard components in the builder.

[image]