# How to use OOTB component Customizable User Settings inside Community

Tags: community, user, component

I'm trying to use this Component inside a Community: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_user_settings_customizable.htm&type=0

Main reason is so Users can change their password inside the Community.

I put the component on a page. But the component isn't displaying. And I think it's because the User ID param is not being provided in any way... but the documentation clearly says "Don’t update this field. The system supplies this value." ... so this component seems broken?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Settings\Advanced - check "Show All Components" as highlighted below, you will be able to see all the standard components in the builder.

[image]

2. Drop the component to page and change parameter to: {!CurrentUser.id} instead of {!userId}

[image]